# How to use ORDERBY with findAll() in Play

Tags: sql-order-by, playframework

is there any way i can use ORDERBY with findAll() in Play Framework?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Model.findAll()` is a shortcut which fetches the results right away, it's equivalent to `Model.all().fetch()`.

I think the best way to specify order is by using a JPQL query like this:

`Model.find("order by fieldName desc").fetch();`

Answer (score 10):

This line seemed to work for me (play 2.1)

```
find.where().orderBy("fieldname desc").findList()
```